# How to get string value from a specific plists in a multiple targets app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, plist, info.plist

In my app there are five targets. Every target has its own plist.

I want to get 2 urls in `AppDelegate` when I build a target. Those 2 urls are different for each target. There are 5 plists (`MyApp1-Info.plist`, `MyApp2-Info.plist`, `MyApp3-Info.plist`, `MyApp4-Info.plist`, `MyApp5-Info.plist`). Each attached with only 1 target.

I have put those urls in plists. If I build `MyApp2` then I should get urls from `MyApp2-Info.plist`. How can I do that? Or is there any better way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to extract data from the `.plist` files *during a build*?

Comment: .plist which is attached with target. YES

Comment: You would need to invoke a *Build Phase* script (running `/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy`).  What do you want to do with the extracted value?

Comment: Those urls are being used in my whole app. But are different for each target

Comment: It's better to use a separate constant per-target, and specify each different value in the target's build settings and then have a header file with `#if defined(TARGET1)  #define URL "url1" #elif defined(TARGET2) #define URL "url2" ...` and forget about `.plist` files (waaay too much aggro).

Comment: Can i get a link explaining this whole process. Never worked with that before

Comment: I don't have a link, but it's pretty standard for multiple targets sharing common source files to "tell" the source file which target they are being compiled for to customize their behaviour.

Comment: Please write it as an answer so i can accept it. And Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better method of using a common source file within multiple targets is to use preprocessor macro that is different for each target.  This directs the source file to perform different actions, or use different values, depending on which target is being compiled.

For example assume you set the prepropressor macro `TARGET` to `1`, `2`, etc. (or something more meaningful to your project), by setting the flag `-DTARGET=1`, `-DTARGET=2`, etc in the Xcode build settings, then the source file can use different URLs as simply as:

```
#if TARGET == 1
#define URL "http://one.com"
#elif TARGET == 2
#define URL "http://two.com"
#else
#error Invalid TARGET value
#endif
```

and away you go.

You can obviously also provide any amount of conditional-compilation using this method, for example:

```
#if TARGET == 1
doSomethingDrastic();
#endif
```

This is a much simpler, and a much more traditional, approach to defining per-target behaviour than embedding stuff within a `.plist` file.

Comment: Sorry just one more thing i want to ask. I added a Debug Preprocessor Macro like this: "DEBUG=1 URL". Do i need to add a Release Preprocessor Macro as well. And if yes then should it be like "RELEASE=1 URL" or something else?

Comment: @Piscean That definition doesn't look right at all (there should be no space between `1` and `URL`), however, you don't need to specify a `RELEASE` macro (the absence of `DEBUG` implies "release mode").

Comment: I changed and its working for me. I was just confused if i need to add Macro for Release as well. So i just leave it empty for Release?

Comment: @Piscean Well you certainly need your *target-specific* macros in both Debug and Release, but they should be the same value for each target, and you should use the `#error` preprocessor statement to catch cases where it's not defined (as shown in my answer), as a safety measure.